# search grep with two parameters exactly

Tags: linux, bash, grep

how to do a grep with two parameter (operation AND); that find all lines that containt the word succeeded and failed exactly.

EG:

```
1. succeeded, failed
2. failed, succeeded
3. failed,failed
4. succeeded, succeeded
5. failed
6. faileds
7. succeeded
```

I need that search return the lines that containt words "succeeded" and "failed", as line 1, 2 and 4

Comment: line 4 does not contain failed, expecting it to match doesn't fit your description.

Comment: I'm assuming these are not your actual words. How would you handle e.g. searching for "bash" and "shell" if the line contained "bashell"? Match because the line contains both substrings? Fail because the words shouldn't match parts of other words? Fail because the strings should not overlap? All the answers currently given take the first approach.

Answer (score 5):

Very simple:

```
grep succeeded | grep failed
```

Alternatively:

```
grep 'succeeded.*failed\|failed.*succeeded'
```

The latter approach doesn't scale very well (you end up with `P(N, N)` subclauses with `N` words), but can be more flexible when handling things like relative position between the words.

Answer (score 3):

first of all, I think line 4 should not be in result. there is no `failed` in it.

```
grep 'succeeded' input|grep 'failed'
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of different approaches that only require a single pass through the file:

```
awk '/succeeded/ && /failed/' file
sed -n '/succeeded/ {/failed/ p}' file
perl -ne 'print if /succeeded/ and /failed/' file
```

I was hoping `grep -e succeeded -e failed file` would work, but it returns "one or the other" instead of "both".

Answer (score 1):

To grep for 2 words existing on the same line with AND

```
grep succeeded FILE | grep failed
```

`grep succeeded FILE` will print all lines that have succeedded in them from FILE, and then `grep failed` will print the lines that have failed in them from the result of  `grep succeeded FILE`. Hence, if you combine these using a pipe, it will show lines containing both succeeded and failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'failed' <(grep 'succeeded' inputFile)
```